# how to think about asynchronous callback operations in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

> Learnyounode is a commandline based learn-by-doing-and-getting-your-results-tested tutorial for javascript's node

In the seventh tutorial, the idea  is to make something of a http client using node.js's http's get function.

The get function has two arguments

1. the url
2. a callback function for the asynchronous job

So I scourgd the surface of the internet looking for a way to continously accept data till the operation ended. After a while seeing that every answer was pretty much along the lines of

```
      function callback(res){

           res.on("data",function (data) { console.log(data.toString());})
   }


  http.get(url,callback)
```

I thought maybe failing the inbuilt tests would give me a clue to see how to make multiple calls but weirdly enough it passed the multiple calls test.So I thought the test called the file and hence the function, multiple times .. but after some tries..I realised that wasn't the case.

So my question : what exactly goes on behind a async call ? how is it possible for the mechanism to call it more than once? What other surprises should I expect ? to me this is taking black box thinking to a whole new level and I place it on par with thinking about list monads atm.

Comment: What is "learnyouanode?"  What programming language are you using?

Comment: @RobertHarvey oh I thought of adding those tags, but then it occured to me this has more to do with the asynchronous nature of node.JS than node.JS. Does that logic not count?

Comment: Actually, the technology and programming language being used is more important.

Comment: Of course, there's nothing that prevents the `get` from calling the `callback` function more than once.

Comment: "*I place it on par with thinking about list monads atm.*" - Huh? If you have understood monads, and want monadic asynchronous actions, then you should look into promises (which guarantee that handlers are called only once)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key point is to understand that `res` is an EventEmitter (IncomingMessage to be more accurate), so what does the function named callback (only once on the `response` event of the httpClientRequest object you create when calling http.get()) is to attach an event listener to the `data` event of res. Without going into details, to optimise data flow, when you receive some data bytes from the network a buffer is filled and when is full the event 'data' is triggered so you can process the incoming chunk. Hence the callback you have set to the `data` event is executed on every chunk of data coming from the network